# can't save form data in joomla 2.5.11

Tags: post, joomla, joomla2.5

my form looks like this :

```
<form class="form-validate" id="booking-form" name="form-booking" method="post" action="/component/booking/?view=booknig">
<div class="width-60 fltlft">
    <fieldset class="form-booking">
        <legend></legend>

        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="readonly" value="0" id="jform_id" name="jform[id]"></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" value="2013-06-17 10:15" name="jform[date_from]"></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" value="1" name="jform[service_id]"></li>
            <li><label class="" for="jform_phone" id="jform_phone-lbl">Telefon</label><input type="text" class="inputbox" value="" id="jform_phone" name="jform[phone]"></li>
            <li><label class="" for="jform_email" id="jform_email-lbl">Email</label><input type="text" class="inputbox" value="" id="jform_email" name="jform[email]"></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" value="" id="jform_checked_out" name="jform[checked_out]"></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" value="" id="jform_checked_out_time" name="jform[checked_out_time]"></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="booking.save" name="task">
<input type="submit" class="button-submit" value="Send" name="Send">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="e391ee49d5291fa9d566236f5c0a435e"> <div class="clr"></div>

</form>
```

and to retrieve POST data i'm using :

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$form_values = $jinput->post->get('jform');
```

but when i'm tring to `print_r` `$form_values` i get only `Array`
where i'm making mistake

Comment: You didn't add the whole form, only input fields. Please provide your <form> tag

Comment: That's because it is an array... you can get/use the values in the array, a starting point is to dump it: `var_dump($form_values)`